# How to find p(A|C) from known values for p(A|B) and p(C|B)?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability, bayes, joint-distribution

Suppose, in some problem with discrete variables, I have found numerical answers for p(A|B) and p(C|B), and have already analytically derived the numerical answers for all their respective associated marginal and joint probabilities -- in other words, I also know p(A), p(B), p(C), p(A & B), and p(B & C). **From here, how do I make the leap to find p(A|C)?**

It seems this should be a simple matter of introductory Bayesian inference -- as if I should be able to easily rearrange any of the following equations algebraically to derive P(A|C) given the values I do know:

- p(A|B) = p(B|A)*p(A)/p(B) = p(A & B)/p(B)   <=== I know all of these
  values
- p(C|B) = p(B|C)*p(C)/p(B) = p(B & C)/p(B)   <=== I know all of
  these values
- p(A|C) = p(C|A)*p(A)/p(C) = p(A & C)/p(C)   <=== I do
  not currently know P(A|C), p(C|A), or P(A & C)

Sorry for the basic question. I feel like I've been unproductively chasing my tail on this!

Answer (score 3):

You do not have enough information.  Consider the following examples.

1) Let $A$ be a random variable symmetric about $0$ ($P(A=x) = P(A=-x)$).  Let $B$ be an independent random variable.  Let $C = A$.

2) Let $A$ be a random variable symmetric about $0$.  Let $B$ be an independent random variable.  Let $C = -A$.

Note that:

- $P(A), P(B), P(C)$ are the same in both examples.
- By independence, then $P(A, B)$ and $P(B, C)$ are the same in both examples.
- However $P(A|C)$ is different in the two examples.

Comment: That makes sense. As such, it seems I've misinterpreted some of the details and specifics in the actual word problem I'm struggling with. (The question I ask above distills my interpretation of a much more verbose, applied problem.)

Comment: Is it possible that you actually know $P(A|B,C)$?

Comment: I believe so. Rearranging that a bit, I have found joint probabilities for P(B | C, A) and P(~B | C, A), and then I can sum those to find the marginal probability, P(A), which I think, or hope, is technically equivalent to P(A | C), due to the conditional term in the original joint probability. I'm not certain how to prove this to myself with equations, but it makes intuitive sense. I'm doing these in simple joint/marginal probability tables, which I know is basic, but I wanted work my way to a more hands-on understanding.

Comment: @m0ckingbird.  $P(B|C,A)$ is a conditional distribution, not a joint distribution, and if can not get you to P(A), which is only equal to P(A|C) if A,C are independent.  You need to be very careful in these waters as intuition can be misleading.  With conditional distribution it often makes sense to sum over things to the left of the "|" but not the things to the right.

Comment: I must be off-track with my terminology, since I thought p(B|C, A) symbolized the joint distribution between (A) and (B|C). As a result, in my joint/marginal probabilities table, the sum of p(B|C, A) + p(~B|C, A) gives me a marginal, "updated"(?) form of p(A)  which is really a conditional p(A|C). In any event, I've likely made some misinterpretations with the way I translated the actual word problem into the simplified ABC notation here, leading to some of my own confusion. This is very useful feedback nonetheless!